# flutter run Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, gradle, flutter

I am receiving this error on first run of a clean new flutter project.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Could not create service of type AnnotationProcessorDetector using JavaGradleScopeServices.createAnnotationProcessorDetector().
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 0s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                         1.5s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Maybe update your gradle to the latest version.

Comment: same issue with my code
see the error details....
https://stackoverflow.com/q/67853201/14380961

Answer (score 0):

open your project and run on your terminal

```
./gradle clean
```

After finishing that, run

```
./gradle build
```

Comment: ./gradle or ./gradlew ?